How to do voice echo cancellation?
I am recording user speech using Windows.Media.Audio.AudioDeviceInputNode. The app uses TTS to speak response through speakers. The issue is that the response is captured on microphone and is treated as further user input.
Here's my setup code:
var pcm16 = AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(16_000, 1, 16);
var audioGraphSettings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Speech)
{
    QuantumSizeSelectionMode = QuantumSizeSelectionMode.ClosestToDesired,
    AudioRenderCategory = AudioRenderCategory.Speech,
    DesiredSamplesPerQuantum = sampleRate / 100,
    EncodingProperties = pcm16,
    
};

CreateAudioGraphResult result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(audioGraphSettings);
if (result.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
{
    throw result.ExtendedError;
}

graph = result.Graph;

var inputProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.High);
inputProfile.Audio = pcm16;

var deviceInputNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(
    MediaCategory.UniformSpeech, // also tried MediaCategory.Speech
    inputProfile.Audio);
if (deviceInputNodeResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
{
    throw deviceInputNodeResult.ExtendedError;
}

AudioDeviceInputNode deviceInputNode = deviceInputNodeResult.DeviceInputNode;

audioNode = graph.CreateFrameOutputNode(pcm16);

deviceInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(audioNode);

graph.QuantumStarted += AudioGraph_QuantumStarted;

graph.Start();

...

void AudioGraph_QuantumStarted(AudioGraph sender, object args) {
  // processing frames here
}

How can I engage built-in echo cancellation (if any)?

Could it be that the build-in AEC is working but unable to cancel the echo due to long echo tail? I suggest to first measure the echo tail/path you have in your system. For more details take a look at https://solicall.com/analyze-the-echo-path-yourself/
